# What were the advantages of having twin agents?

Tags: quantico

In the first series of Quantico, Nimah and Raina Amin are recruited by Miranda Shaw, following her belief that identical twins have built-in advantages over other agents.

There are a few supposed demonstrations of what these advantages could be:

- They are able to convince people they are a single agent.
- They are able to cross the US border under a single passport.
- They are able to pass information from terrorist cells.

Obviously, all of these "advantages" seem to also be possible with just a single agent, and there are also disadvantages; for example, injuries need to match exactly and heal at the same rate.

So: **What specific advantages did Miranda see in recruiting twins?**

Answer (score 3):

While one of the twin is working as normal person, the second can work as FBI agent and steal secret at all time. So FBI gets 24 hour agent while having a disclosed identity.

Also there is another benefit too like the single agent can have or trained to get certain interest but twins can have it double. So at the same time twins can use these interest to catch up with more people than single agent.

Also, single agent has to maintain his mental ability too. As we can see alex's father is a hero but at home he is not stable. But If you have someone who can take your place when and where you want to take break, its the bigger advantage.

It has the disadvantages you notices correctly but the trial is there for to get what issues they face and on next selection they choose such twin who can overcome such issue like healing same time.